# dns resolution fails

Tags: centos, dns, bridge

I'm following the [cloudstack quick installation guide](https://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/en/4.19.0.0/quickinstallationguide/qig.html#) to try out cloudstack. As server I use a centos vm. After the first step *Configuring the Network*, dns resolution fails, preventing my to make any progress in the guide.

### system information

[image]

### config files

**cloudbr0**
[image]

**eth0**
[image]

**resolv.conf**
[image]

### network config

[image]

sorry for adding all those screenshots. I'm running this vm in virtmanager and cannot connect with ssh.

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397)

Comment: I don't know how to copy text from a virtmanager VM window. So I had no other option.

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering around, the problem was not on my side. My university has two Wifi networks. In one, `ping` works, but dns resolution doesn't. In the other, `ping` doesn't work, but dns resolution does.
To resolve this problem, I connected my laptop to LAN and now both `ping` and DNS works as expected.